# Apache - .htaccess: mod_rewrite and ErrorDocument won't work together

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I'm not sure what the mistake is here, but I'm not able to redirect 404 errors to a specific page. This is how the .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.someurl.com/error404/404.php
```

The error folder and file exist, and when I do a `curl -i http://www.someurl.com/notexistent` it returns a correct 404 error code. But no redirection, neither curl, nor in the browser. How is that possible?
Sorry, I'm no expert with these .htaccess configurations, help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
I tried different url's like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.someurl.com/error404/
ErrorDocument 404 /error404/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error404/
```

But withouth success.

**EDIT 2:**
I forgot to mention: mod_rewrite works as expected. Only the 404 redirects do not work.

Answer (score 0):

With your `RewriteRule` you rewrite all the pages without real file or folder to `index.php` no exceptions for 404 errors...

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php? [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer :) Can you help me fix this?

Comment: No, I can't If I don't know what you try to do... You rewrite all pages without real file to `index.php`. Don't do that (delete the line `RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php`) if you like the 404 page, just use the `ErrorDocument 404`. In which cases would you like to see this page 404 and In which cases would you like to see `index.php` ???

Comment: Ok, right. I should've been more specific. The rule that rewrites all non-existing pages to index.php does not seem to work. When I visit a non-existing link, I just see a blank page, though I'm not redirected to index.php or /. So, what I want to do is, that when a non-existing file/folder is visited a) there should be a redirect to index.php or / OR b) a redirect to a 404 page. I'd prefer a) but with my .htaccess neither of these redirects work :(

Comment: Try now with my .htaccess in the answer part.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but did not have success: When i deleted the line `RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php` the redirect of non-existing pages to index.php did infact work, but none of the real, existing links of the page worked anymore. So, I read a lot about php today and then looked at the index.php. The way I understand it is, that in index.php there is a "query" (not yet sure what that is exactly), and I think i need to fix/troubleshoot/edit this query. So I'll have to dig deeper. I don't think it's a problem with the .htaccess Thanks a lot for your help, and for asking the right questions :)